# marshal_as String from const char* does not work

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**Method1:**

```
const char * name = pXml->GetChildAttrib(_T("name")).c_str();
screenSet->Name = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String ^>(name);
```

**Method2:**

```
CString name = pXml->GetChildAttrib(_T("name")).c_str();
screenSet->Name = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String ^>((const char *)name);
```

**Method1** does **NOT** work. It just returns empty string.

**Method2** works, and returns the actual string to **screenSet->Name**.

I just wonder why. They look the same.

Comment: what is the error for Method1?

Comment: @Matt No error, just return empty string, but the method2 gives the string to me

Comment: what is pXML? and the implementation of GetChildAttrib?

Comment: It quacks like a problem with the temporary C string returned by c_str().  The CString copies it immediately so the exact moment the temporary is destroyed doesn't matter.  Life is not that easy without a garbage collector :)  Do note that converting from Unicode to a const char* and back again to Unicode is unwise.  Using `gcnew String(pXml->GetChildAttrib(L"name"))` is *much* preferable.

Comment: @Matt I use CMarkupSTL to get the content of XML

Comment: @HansPassant Thank for your suggestion. Yours does work greatly